Installation error (MySQL)
I am trying to install CiviCRM, but when I get to the point of installing it within WordPress, I get the following errors:
Severity (error)    Section (Databases)
[Name + Details 1]: CiviCRM MySQL Lock Tables + Could not create a table
[Name + Details 2]: CiviCRM MySQL Temp Tables + Database does not support creation of temporary tables
[Name + Details 3]: CiviCRM MySQL Trigger + Database does not support creation of triggers
Do you know How I can fix this? I'm hosting my website via Netim and I access the databases via PhpMyAdmin.
Thanks in advance!

Your hosting will need to allow creating temporary tables and triggers, and grant the mysql user those permissions. This is required to run civicrm.
https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#mysql-permissions
